# What is the replacement for Context.Row and Context.Record when reading a CSV file?

Tags: csvhelper

I was using v18 of CsvHelp and using Context.Row and Context.Record when reading a CSV file. I'm upgrading to v27 but these are no longer available. Does anyone know what the replacements for them are please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parser.RawRow and Parser.RawRecord are the replacements for Context.Row and Context.Record.